# Instagram Fetch Amount of Images API

Tags: php, api, instagram

A friend of mine wrote this script, displaying the 20 most recent instagram images, and I was wondering, how can I change the amount of images it grabs to maybe, 6?

```
    <?PHP
$token = 'token';

$username = 'username';

$userInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='.$username.'&access_token='.$token));

if($userInfo->meta->code==200){

    $photoData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$userInfo->data[0]->id.'/media/recent/?access_token='.$token));

    if($photoData->meta->code==200){ ?>

                <?PHP foreach($photoData->data as $img){
                    echo '<a href="'.$img->link.'?intent=like" target="_blank"><img src="'.$img->images->thumbnail->url.'"></a>';
                } ?>

    <?PHP } // If

} // If
    ?>
```

Now, the script is functional now because I've been working on it all day, but I'm not sure how to change how many it sends out.

Also, would any of you know how to style this? I already have the CSS done for it, but whenever I try it, it doesn't work correctly.

And, would you know how to get the description of the photo using the API?

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Instagram's [`count=`](http://instagram.com/developer/search/?q=count%3D) url parameter when requesting data from their endpoints.

For example: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?count=6`

Or in your code:

```
<?PHP
$token = 'token';

$username = 'username';

$userInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?count=6&q='.$username.'&access_token='.$token));

if($userInfo->meta->code==200){

    $photoData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$userInfo->data[0]->id.'/media/recent/?count=6&access_token='.$token));

    if($photoData->meta->code==200){ ?>

                <?PHP foreach($photoData->data as $img){
                    echo '<a href="'.$img->link.'?intent=like" target="_blank"><img src="'.$img->images->thumbnail->url.'"></a>';
                } ?>

    <?PHP } // If

} // If
?>
```

Pseudo example for styling. You'll need to figure out the css styles for that, but shouldn't be to difficult.

```
<div class='myBorder'>
    <img url=$img->link />
    <div class='myCaption'>$img->caption->text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, no problem! As for styling, not sure what you want to accomplish, but you can spit out any styled html/css you want with PHP.

Comment: Well, I was just wondering how I would be able to put the image into a box with and have the image's caption in a box below it, like this. http://codyleek.me/cdn/img/p8fprx.png. I mean, I have it styled already, I just don't know how to do it so it does it for each image.

Comment: I'll write a quick pseudo example in the answer, you can see if you can make something out of it.

Comment: Alright, I got the caption working, but it only works for the last image, and all of the images are displaying in one box. Zoomed out so you can see. http://codyleek.me/cdn/img/ksSZ1h.png

Comment: You know, I'm gonna try repeating the code 6 times, but change the count to one, so then it's in separate boxes.

EDIT:
I've tried that and it just displays the first image. Figured.

Comment: What you had before was right, but the div/img/caption etc. needs to be inside the loop, so that each time it loops through the returned data it spits out a new div, caption, image.

Comment: And the loop would be the `foreach()` right? Or is is the bit that's in the echo?

Comment: `foreach(.....) { echo div, img, caption };` I'm on a mobile device right now so can't write the whole thing out.

Comment: Alright, so I did this:
`<?PHP foreach($photoData->data as $img){
                        echo '<a href="'.$img->link.'?intent=like" target="_blank"><img src="'.$img->images->thumbnail->url.'"></a>';
                        echo '<header>'.$img->caption->text;'</header>';}
                        
?>`
And ended up with this
http://codyleek.me/cdn/img/Pea0Yz.png

I'm really sorry if I'm bothering you, lol.

Comment: you're on the right track -- see if you can get it styled right with static (non API) data first (even play around in jsFiddle and see if you can get it working). Also don't use <header> in there like that, it's intended to be the actual document (page) header.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I've gotten it to work correctly so each box gets an image and a caption, but it's going down vertically. Do you know of a way I can get it to go horizontally? Even better, with three boxes in each row?

Comment: `float: left;` on each one's parent div, then you'll need a wrapper div around ALL of them with a fixed width so that they wrap around. If each is `100px` wide (including all margins, padding, borders), make your wrapping div `300px`.

Comment: They aren't breaking their vertical form.

Comment: Best thing to do is post what you have now in a new question, get it in to a jsFiddle (and post the code) and see if you can get some help that way ;) too hard to figure out without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the description

```
if (isset($img->caption)) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $title = stripslashes($img->caption->text);
    } else {
        $title = $img->caption->text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still returns 20 rows of data though.. even though it slices.

Comment: Please do some searches when we give you a part of the solution... :)

Comment: It was sliced into rows of 6 before. I found no change.
And sorry, zeflex. I'm new to all of this stuff.

Comment: At least you have the count in the other answer, so I remove this part from my answer.